# Laravel Mail::send with a mail->to loop

Tags: laravel

I try to fill the receiver of an email from database. If I write the adress direct to $mail->to everything works fine but not with this code?:

```
$users = User::where('message_receiver','=',true)->get();
$data = array(
    'url'   =>  Config::get('app.url'),
    'name'  => 'test'
);

Mail::send('emails.message', $data, function($mail) use ($users)
{
    $mail->from('test@localhost.de','test@localhost.de');
    foreach ($users AS $user) {
        $mail->to($user->email, $user->firstname.' '.$user->surname);
    }
    $mail->subject('New Message');
});
```

`print_r($user->email)` in the loop dumps the correct adress!

Comment: Are you sure, you want all the addresses to be listed and visible for all recipients? Instead do look for `Mail::send` and process one user at the time.

Comment: Hi, yes in this case it is no problem if all adresses are listed.

Answer (score 1):

I never work with Laravel, but by this link http://bundles.laravel.com/bundle/Messages

As I understand, to send emails to multiple email addresses, you have to add all addresses into array first, then pass that array to `$message->to()` method, don't you?

And this is a sample from that link:

```
Message::send(function($message)
{
    $message->to(array('someone@gmail.com', 'email@address.com' => 'name'));
    $message->cc('more@addresses.com');
    $messages->bcc(array('evenmore@address.com' => 'Another name', 'onelast@address.com'));

    $message->from('me@gmail.com', 'Bob Marley');
    $message->subject('Hello!');
    $message->body('I really like spamming people!');
});
```

So, in my idea, you should try to make array from `$users` and then pass it to the method, something like this:

```
Mail::send('emails.message', $data, function($mail) use ($users)
{
    $mail->from('test@localhost.de','test@localhost.de');
    foreach ($users AS $user) {
        $receivers = array_add($receivers, $user->email, $user->email);
    }
    $mail->to($receivers);
    $mail->subject('New Message');
});
```

I'm not sure if I used array correctly, but I think you have alredy know how to do that.